# Function argument converted to date

Tags: r, function

I have a function with an argument that is a link to a file. My problem is, that even though I specify that I want to have a string here, a part of it seems to be recognized as a date. This results in a part of my string being replaced by "t-". How do I prevent this from happening?

```
smfunc <- function(link=as.character("T:\11-10-2017 - Folder\filename.csv"))
  {
  link
  }

smfunc()

[1] "T:\t-10-2017 - Folder\filename.csv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I prevent this from happening?

Easy: this **does not happen** (that would be terrible). The problem is different: [you forgot to escape the backslashes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html):

```
smfunc = function (link = "T:\\11-10-2017 - Folder\\filename.csv") {
    link
}
```

Without the escaped backslashes, `'\11'` is interpreted as a numeric character code (with value 11<sub>oct</sub> = 9<sub>dec</sub>, which is equivalent to the tab character `'\t'`).

`'\f'`, by pure chance, is a valid escape sequence equivalent to the “form feed” character. This is *not* the same as `'\\f'`, i.e. a literal backslash followed by an “f”, and which is what you need.

Using `as.character`, incidentally, is redundant here: your value is already a character vector.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer.